# Android Live Wallpaper onOffsetsChanged

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make a live wallpaper. I understand that onOffsetsChanged method is used to get the current position of the screen. I am not able to properly understand how to implement this  method to get the livewallpaper or just even a standard wallpaper to move sideways along with the user swipes. I tries looking through some examples but still i am not clear. Can someone give me an idea and suggest some good tutorial for a live wallpaper that can move across the screen with user swipes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this post maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637753/using-onoffsetschanged-to-get-home-screen-swipe-direction

Comment: Got a reply here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816432

Answer (score 1):

you need to make

```
public float mmPixel;
```

and then

```
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
            float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {

        mmPixel = xPixels;



    }
```

and draw your Bitmap like this on Canvas c

```
    c.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, mmPixel, 0, null);
```